# Custom layout, onMeasure/onLayout called continuously

Tags: java, android, layout, custom-controls, android-relativelayout

I coded my own Layout (sublclassing a RelativeLayout). I see from debugger that onMeasure() and onLayout() are called continuously. Is it a normal behaviour? The stack trace starts from a dispatchMessage():

```
Synoptic.onMeasure(int, int) line: 125  
Synoptic(View).measure(int, int) line: 12727    
RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(View, RelativeLayout$LayoutParams, int, int) line: 594    
RelativeLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 376    
RelativeLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12727  
LinearLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4698    
LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(View, int, int, int, int, int) line: 1369 
LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(int, int) line: 1017 
LinearLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 555  
LinearLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12727    
SwipeView(HorizontalScrollView).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 1159    
SwipeView(FrameLayout).onMeasure(int, int) line: 293    
SwipeView(HorizontalScrollView).onMeasure(int, int) line: 303   
SwipeView(View).measure(int, int) line: 12727   
LinearLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4698    
LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(View, int, int, int, int, int) line: 1369 
LinearLayout.measureVertical(int, int) line: 660    
LinearLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 553  
LinearLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12727    
LinearLayout.measureVertical(int, int) line: 812    
LinearLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 553  
LinearLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12727    
FrameLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4698 
FrameLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 293   
FrameLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12727 
LinearLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4698    
LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(View, int, int, int, int, int) line: 1369 
LinearLayout.measureVertical(int, int) line: 660    
LinearLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 553  
LinearLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12727    
PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4698   
PhoneWindow$DecorView(FrameLayout).onMeasure(int, int) line: 293    
PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(int, int) line: 2092    
PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).measure(int, int) line: 12727   
ViewRootImpl.performTraversals() line: 1068 
ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(Message) line: 2446  
ViewRootImpl(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4424    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 784  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 551 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

**and here the onLayout():**

```
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

       if (changed) {

        itemGrid.getLayoutParams().width = (int) itemSize;
        itemGrid.getLayoutParams().height = (int) itemSize;

        itemProduction.getLayoutParams().width = (int) itemSize;
        itemProduction.getLayoutParams().height = (int) itemSize;

        itemConsumption.getLayoutParams().width = (int) itemSize;
        itemConsumption.getLayoutParams().height = (int) itemSize;

        imageViewFlowAnimation.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animationHeight;
        imageViewFlowAnimation.getLayoutParams().width = (int) animationWidth;
}   
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your `onLayout()` and `onMeasure()` methods?

Comment: Ok I added some code, itemGrid, itemProduction, itemConsumption and imageViewFlowAnimation are RelativeLayout children

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be calling `super` in either method.  That's what's putting into an endless loop.  You also need to ensure that you call `setMeasuredDimension();` from `onMeasure()` or it will throw an exception.

Comment: If I don't call super() in onLayout() I see nothing on the screen. Note that I load the layout xml by calling layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ui_synoptic, this, true); on the creator. The xml contains a RelativeLayout itself

Comment: Then try just not calling it in `onMeasure()` but be sure to call `setMeasuredDimension()`.

Comment: I changed: no override of onMeasure and only one row on onLayout that ajust child layour with child.layout(). Same effect.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the child that forces its parent to recalc the layout?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:
if (changed) super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

Comment: Usefull to check for the changed parameter. But I noticed that the loop is interrupted only if I omit to override the onMeasure().

Comment: I solved using if (changed) {<<set the childrend size>>} and putting the super.onLayout() outside the if block.